# How can I parse a # from a macro argument?

Tags: macros, xstring

I want to write a macro such that `\ghpr{myrepo#1234}` expands to `\href{https://github.com/my-username/myrepo/pull/1234}{myrepo#1234}`.
(I know how to do it for `\ghpr{myrepo}{1234}`, but I'd prefer to keep the `#` separator if possible.)

My attempt at doing this is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\ghpr[1]{%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{##}{/pull/}[\tmpurl]%
  \href{https://github.com/my-username/\tmpurl}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\ghpr{myrepo#1234}
\end{document}
```

but this produces `Illegal parameter number in definition of \xs_arg_ii` when I try to use it.

I assume the problem here is that I'm not escaping the `#` correctly; how should I be writing this command?

Comment: @Teepeemm: Yes, it works fine if I write the macro that way, but then at the call site I have to write `\ghpr{mathlib/pull/8105}`; I wanted to be able to write `\ghpr{mathlib#8105}` and have the macro insert the `/pull/` string for me.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your point now; I somehow need to tell LaTeX that it should not parse the # at the callsite. Is this possible?

Comment: `\newcommand\ghpr[2]{\href{https://github.com/my-username/#1/pull/#2}{#1\##2}` and then `\ghpr{myrepo}{1234}`.

Comment: @Skillmon: sure, I know I can do it that way. I was hoping I could write it as a single argument with a `#` between the parts. If you think that's a really bad idea (or know it's impossible), I'd also accept an answer explaining why.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use `#`? It would be easy to do with another separator, if there's a suitable alternative which won't occur in the values. For example, it would easy to make it work for something like `\ghpr{mathlib:8105}` or `\ghpr{mathlib:8015,mathslib:8106,mathxlib:9834}` (for 3 links). Then you can just split the argument as the first step.

Comment: You described desired behavior only for one kind of possibility how the argument of `\ghpr` could look like. Can you give a description of desired behavior for all kinds of how the argument of `\ghpr` can look like? E.g., what to do in case the argument is empty/blank or contains no hash `#` at all or contains several hashes as in `\ghpr{foo#bar-baz#bat}` or contains expandable/unexpandable control sequence tokens?

Comment: Anything not of the provided form (containing exactly one hash) should be an error

Answer (score 4):

I can understand your wish for `#` as the argument delimiter, but note that this is a hard to parse for character in TeX due to its nature as the parameter token.

Anyway, the following proposes 3 solutions to make this work.

- `\ghprDetok` would break any macros or special characters (read: non-ASCII in pdfTeX) in your argument, but is the fastest of them
- `\ghprEtl` is the second fastest (but stable)
- `\ghprRegex` is the slowest (but stable)

In none of the three do I check whether an `#` was actually part of the argument (which would result in a low level TeX error in the `\ghprDetok` and `\ghprEtl` and lead to an empty numeric part in `\ghprRegex`). If you need detection here I can add it for all three variants.

The `\ghprEtl` variant reuses the internal of the `\ghprDetok`, which wouldn't be necessary but it'd need an auxiliary so why not reuse the other one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etl}

\newcommand*\ghprfastest[2]
  {\href{https://github.com/my-username/#1/pull/#2}{#1\##2}}%

\newcommand*\ghprDetok[1]
  {\expandafter\ghprDetokAUX\detokenize{#1}\stop}
\expanded{\unexpanded{\def\ghprDetokAUX#1}\string#\string#}#2\stop
  {\ghprfastest{#1}{#2}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \ghprEtl #1
  {%
    \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \ghprDetokAUX
      { \etl_token_replace_once:nNe {#1} ## { \c_hash_str\c_hash_str } }
    \stop
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \etl_token_replace_once:nNn { nNe }

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \ghprRegex #1
  {
    \regex_split:nnN { \# } {#1} \l_tmpa_seq
    \exp_args:Nee \ghprfastest
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 1 }
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ghprfastest{myrepo}{1234}

\ghprDetok{myrepo#1234}

\ghprEtl{myrepo#1234}

\ghprRegex{myrepo#1234}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change catcode of `#` locally:

```
\def\ghpr{\bgroup \catcode`\#=12 \ghprA}
\def\ghprA #1{\egroup \href{https://github.com/my-username/myrepo/pull/1234}{#1}}

\ghpr{myrepo#1234} % expands to \href{https://github.com/my-username/myrepo/pull/1234}{myrepo#1234}
```

Comment: Nice solution, unfortunately it works only if a category code change still works. Anyway +1.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "still works" @Skillmon?

Comment: @Eric this would fail if `\ghpr` is part of an argument to another macro (`\textbf{\ghpr{abc#123}}` would fail).

Comment: In my document I have a handful of `\footnote{See \ghpr{abc#123}}`s. I guess it will fail there?

Comment: @Eric correct, it would.

Comment: In plain TeX, `\footnote{See \ghpr{abc#123}}` doesn't fail, because `{...}` is not macro parameter here. And we write `{\bf something}`, so there isn't macro parameter too.

Comment: But the `#1` if footnote mark, not the footnote text. OK, I bring the confusion here because I didn't write my example correctly in my previous comment. Should be correct: `\footnote1{See \ghpr{abc#123}`